# How do I change one value in an array but leave the rest alone? - VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

Imagine you have 7 values `50/50/50/50/50/50/50` and you want to change just one when a criteria is me so it becomes `50/50/50/49/50/50/50` But then it saves this new array so if another criteria is met it could become something like `49/50/50/49/50/50/50`
I've tried this a hundred times and it just doesn't work. Heres what I have so far

```
Dim StreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("D:\CALLUMS STUFF\Coursework\Stock.Txt")

Dim StreamRead As String

 Dim StreamArray() As String

Dim X As String

 Do  StreamReader.Peek() <> -1

StreamRead = (StreamReader.ReadLine())

 StreamArray = StreamRead.Split("/")



 X = StreamArray(9)

Loop

Dim C As String

C = X - 1



Select Case CmbSize.SelectedIndex

Case 0

Dim StockWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\CALLUMS STUFF\Courseworkd\Stock.Txt")

StockWriter.Write(C(9))

 End Select
```

Comment: `YourArray(4) = 49`? it's not exactly rocket science...

Comment: I think you are writing the wrong data back. What value does C(9) have?. As Marc B wrote, you set StreamArray(9) to your value, and write back the COMPLETE Array to your file.

Comment: there are so many redundant variable assignments here........

Comment: This is prone for many issues, also are you only wanting to change only one specific index in the array all the time and is it going to exist all the time?

Comment: I want it to keep going down, so it saves the new value as that value, and will minus 1 from that value next time. So e.g 50/50/50 to 50/49/50 then 49/49/50 or 50/48/50

Comment: I want to change any index, depending on the criteria matched. But I then want it to save the new array for use next time.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to use `Option Strict On`. You've got so much implicit conversion going on I'm surprised that even comes close to working. Look at what I put below and try implementing parts of it and see if it doesn't help out.

btw, I wrote it as a console application. So if you want it to actually work on your machine, you'll have to add a reference to `System.windows.Forms` in the project settings and you'll have to change the file paths in the constructors for the streamreader/writer.

> Contents of C:\StackOverflow\stock.txt
>
> > 50/50/50/50/50/50/50

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim arrfileContents As String()

        ' Get the data
        Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\StackOverflow\stock.txt")
            arrfileContents = sr.ReadToEnd.Split(CChar("/"))
        End Using

        ' I'm guessing at what cmbSize is... A ComboBox made sense since you 
        ' have cmb in the name and you are accessing the .SelectedIndex
        ' property which a ComboBox has. If you wanted, a ListBox would also
        ' work instead
        Dim cmbSize As New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

        ' Add the items to the Combobox. For simplicity I'm just going to
        ' put the contents of the file in the ComboBox.Items. That way I 
        ' know that the arrFileContents.count and cmbSize.Items.Count are
        ' the same.
        cmbSize.Items.AddRange(arrfileContents)

        ' Need this to select something other that the first item
        ' This would be like setting criteria to be matched, if this were
        ' a winforms application I would be putting this in the method that 
        ' handles the SelectedIndexChanged event 
        cmbSize.SelectedIndex = CInt((cmbSize.Items.Count - 1) / 2)

        'Get and change the Value if valid
        Dim tempvalue As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(arrfileContents(cmbSize.SelectedIndex), tempvalue) AndAlso tempvalue <> Integer.MinValue Then
            tempvalue -= 1
            arrfileContents(cmbSize.SelectedIndex) = tempvalue.ToString
        End If


        ' Write the data back out
        Using sw As New StreamWriter("C:\StackOverflow\stock.txt")
            sw.Write(String.Join("/", arrfileContents))
        End Using

    End Sub

End Module
```